# WARNING: all packages have been deleted from this repository

Tags: repository

I have visited several repositories which have that statement. What is really going on.

Edit: To clarify the question. If the repository doesn't exist, where did they move it to? How do I fix getting the stable repository?

Because when I use the link provided at that page it gives me this:
**Not allowed here
Sorry, you don't have permission to access this page.**

Here's and example: http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppas/14

When you arrive this is what you get
[image]

Comment: I've just checked it and you're true. Which other PPAs are affected according to you?

Comment: From visiting the official PPA page and logging in it tells me I don't have access. So, perhaps they've turned it into a private PPA instead of a public?

Comment: What's the question here? That PPA doesn't exist anymore so the page is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The repository has moved. It doesn't mean the files don't exist just placed somewhere else.